# Проблема с Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint

возникла вот такая проблема с Linux mint mate после его установки. При первом запуске у меня был какой-то размазанный рабочий стол, не понятно что и где, перезапустил и теперь у меня ос отказывается запускаться.Когда я использовал демку с загрузочный флешки в режиме совместимости все было ок. Не могу сфотографировать то что теперь происходит на экране, но попробую написать что там происходит. BusyBox v1. 30.1(Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built in shell (ash) Enter help for a list of built-in commands.

Comment: Не знаю, даёт ли минт при установке возможность выбрать драйвер. Если даёт, то выбирайте открытый, а проприетарный установите в конце самостоятельно. Возможно он просто криво установился из скрипта.